# How to slice a n dimensional array with a m*(n-i) dimensional matrix?

Tags: r, slice

If i have a *n* dimensional array it can be sliced by a *m* * *n* matrix like this

```
a <- array(1:27,c(3,3,3))

b <- matrix(rep(1:3,3),3)

# This will return the index a[1,1,1] a[2,2,2] and a[3,3,3]
a[b]

# Output
[1]  1 14 27
```

Is there any "effective and easy" way to do a similar slice but to keep some dimensions free?
That is slice a n dimensional array with a *m* * *(n-i)* dimensional array and
get a *i+1* dimensional array as result.

```
a <- array(1:27,c(3,3,3))

b <- matrix(rep(1:2,2),2)

# This will return a vector of the index a[1] a[2] a[1] and a[2]
a[b]

# Output
[1] 1 2 1 2


# This will return the indexes of the cartesian product between the vectors,
# that is a array consisting of a[1,,1] a[1,,2] a[2,,1] and a[2,,2]
a[c(1,2),,c(1,2)]

# Output
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   13   16
[2,]   11   14   17
```

The desired result should be if the last command returned an array
with a[1,,1] and a[2,,2].
For now I solve this the problem with a for loop and abind but I'm sure there must be a better way.

```
# Desired functionality
a <- array(1:27,c(3,3,3))
b <- array(c(c(1,2),c(1,2)),c(2,2))
sliceem(a,b,freeDimension=2)

# Desired output (In this case rbind(a[1,,1],a[2,,2]) ) 
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]   11   14   17
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the cleanest way -- making a separate function:

```
slicem <- function(a,idx,drop=FALSE) do.call(`[`,c(list(a),idx,list(drop=drop)))

# usage for OP's example
a      <- array(1:27, c(3,3,3))    
idx    <- list(1:2, TRUE, 1:2)
slicem(a,idx)
```

which gives

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   13   16
[2,]   11   14   17
```

You have to write `TRUE` for each dimension that you aren't selecting from.

---

*Following the OP's new expectations...*

```
library(abind)
nistfun <- function(a,list_o_idx,drop=FALSE){
  lens <- lengths(list_o_idx)
  do.call(abind, lapply(seq.int(max(lens)), function(i)
    slicem(a, mapply(`[`, list_o_idx, pmin(lens,i), SIMPLIFY=FALSE), drop=drop)
  ))
}

# usage for OP's new example
nistfun(a, idx)

# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    7
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   11   14   17
```

Now, any non-`TRUE` indices must have the same length, since they will be matched up.

`abind` is used here instead of `rbind` (see an earlier edit on this answer) because it is the only sensible general way to think about slicing up an array. If you really want to drop dimensions, it's quite ambiguous which should be dropped and how, so the vector alone is returned:

```
nistfun(a, idx, drop=TRUE)
# [1]  1  4  7 11 14 17
```

If you want to throw this back into an array of some sort, you can do that after the fact:

```
matrix( nistfun(a, idx), max(lengths(idx)), dim(a)[sapply(idx,isTRUE)]), byrow=TRUE)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    7
# [2,]   11   14   17
```

Comment: Sorry for taking back the accepting as answer but I realised that your function return the indexes from the cartesian product of the two vectors.
The desired result (as stated in the question) should just be
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]   11   14   17

Comment: @nist I don't really follow what you're saying. In the question, you say the desired output is `a[c(1,2),,c(1,2)]`, which is the same as what I have here...or am I misunderstanding? The numbers you're giving in your comment appear nowhere in the question...

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The problem is that the slice creates all possible combinations of the vectors, I want the first elements in the vectors to be paired and then the all elements at the second position and so on. The function must work for higher dimensional arrays and with multiple free dimensions

Comment: @nist I really don't think you've thought through the expected behavior when there are multiple free dimensions. Maybe you should post a new question once you have.

Comment: will repost the question and see if I can be more specific

Comment: The new question is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947700/how-to-slice-a-n-dimensional-array-with-a-mn-i-dimensional-matrix-keeping-som?noredirect=1#comment51805918_31947700 hope it will be easier to understand